# Animation on exit

Tags: android, animation

I have around 10 different buttons in a screen. When I click on a button, the resulting activity should pop out from within the button. When I go back the activity should pop in.

NOTE : I cannot use a pop up window, because it is a heavy weight activity. ANd it has a flow within it.

So i guessed that I would have to get the X and Y coordinates  on run time.

```
pivotX = getIntent().getFloatExtra("pivotX", 0);
pivotY = getIntent().getFloatExtra("pivotY", 0);
v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(getResourceID(), null);
v.setAnimation(Animation);
//where Animation uses pivotX and pivotY
setContentView(v);
```

So this solved the issue while launching. But when I want it to zoom back to the original position(when activity closes), I am facing problem.

This is because the view is detatched prior to onpause or any such activity.

overridePending Transaction would not help because I need the X and Y coordinates dynamically.

Need some help regarding it. Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

You could set the second activity to `screenOrientation="behind"` in the manifest, so you can reuse the same pivotX and pivotY when closing the activity.

Comment: screenorientaion is tha layout. But i would need the position from which it was launched.

Answer (score 0):

I atlast got the solution with the help of the following [Link](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/jb-mr1-dev/samples/devbytes/animation/ActivityAnimations/src/com/example/android/activityanim/PictureDetailsActivity.java)